# Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference. Only in Webkit/Safari in Angular production build

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, safari, webkit

I've developed a project using Angular.
When I build it using for production I get no errors and everything works fine on Chrome.
If I run the app on Webkit/Safari the console prints this error:

> SyntaxError: Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference.
> (funzione anonima) — main.ebe5d823e9b701706d6f.js:1
> Elemento selezionato

Here is the content of main.ebe5d823e9b701706d6f.js (formatted by the browser):

```
(self.webpackChunkfrontend = self.webpackChunkfrontend || []).push([[179], {
3597: t => {
    function e(t) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + t + "'");
            throw e.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", e
        })
    }
    e.keys = () => [],
    e.resolve = e,
    e.id = 3597,
    t.exports = e
},
88642: (t, e, n) => {
    "use strict";
    n.d(e, {
        T: () => l
    });
```

I don't think that the error is thrown by `self.webpackChunkfrontend = self.webpackChunkfrontend` but I don't know how to solve it because the browser doesn't says which is the assignment that causes the error.

Comment: why not put `e.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"` in the line above `throw e` and see if that helps - oh, wait this is code that is "built" by something isn't it

Comment: Yes, it is built by webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `buildOptimizer=false` to `angular.json` seems to solve the issue for versions 11 and down. In the GitHub repo they say that this issue is fixed for versions 12+ but I haven't tested it to confirm it.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21107

Comment: I have tried it and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue.

The problem was caused by the npm module `three`. There is a problem in the `isSpotLight` method.

I've removed the feature that was using that module, so now the app works also on Safari/WebKit.

These are the steps that I've followed to debug the issue:

- Copy the content of main.ebe5d823e9b701706d6f.js
- Go to an online JS Beautifier
- Paste the code and beautify it
- Copy the beautified code to main.ebe5d823e9b701706d6f.js
- Reload the page in Safari. Now the console prints the correct line number with the error.